# Pandas groupby get month and year values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe (50000 lines for 2016,2017,2018):

```
data.head()
             Values
Date              
2016-07-20    10.0
2016-07-20    10.0
2016-07-22     1.0
2016-07-22     1.0
2016-07-22     1.0
```

simple `groupby` :

```
data.groupby([(data1.index.year==2018),(data1.index.month==5)])['Values'].sum()

False  False   1461787.35
       True      80714.53
True   False    862589.66
       True     172600.04
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

How can I change `False` and `True` in `year` and `month` to 2018 and 5 ?

Output expected :

```
    2018     5   80714.53
    Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry, what is expected output?

Comment: The same but with numbers in place of (false/true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need grouping by `year`s and `month`s only:

```
#changed data for better sample
print (data)

            Values
Date              
2015-07-20    10.0
2015-05-20    20.0
2016-05-20     2.0
2018-05-22     1.0
2018-05-22     3.0
2018-07-22     4.0

df1 = data.groupby([data.index.year, data.index.month])['Values'].sum()
print (df1)
Date  Date
2015  5       20.0
      7       10.0
2016  5        2.0
2018  5        4.0
      7        4.0
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

Your solution grouping by boolean mask, `True` are filtered only `2018` years and `False`s are all non `2018` rows, similar for `month`s:

```
df2 = data.groupby([(data.index.year==2018),(data.index.month==5)])['Values'].sum()
print (df2)
False  False    10.0
       True     22.0
True   False     4.0
       True      4.0
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

If want only filtered values is possible use:

```
df = data[(data.index.year==2018) & (data.index.month==5)]
print (df)
            Values
Date              
2018-05-22     1.0
2018-05-22     3.0

out = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])['Values'].sum()
print (out)
Date  Date
2018  5       4.0
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i ' m looking for

Comment: @Math - You are welcome! Also added samples for better understand difference.